# Get list of installed applications on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I want to get a list of applications installed by the user on Ubuntu. Installed packages can be listed by

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

I couldn't find how to get only applications and also installed by the user (not by default).

**xfce4-appfinder** does exactly the thing that I want but it is GUI based.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `aptitude` installed, then:

```
aptitude search '~i !~M !~E'
```

should do it.

`~i` for installed

`!~M` for not (`!`) automatically installed (i.e. dependencies)

`!~E` for not (`!`) essential system packages

Comment: It still shows so many packages-dependencies for an entry, for instance, unity. I also do not want unity be in the list though.

Comment: You could substract the output in freshly installed system from this backup.